# XMLStreamReader doesn't read complete tag

Tags: java, xml

I'm parsing XML using `XMLStreamReader`. In `<dbresponse>` tag there are some data loaded from database (`WebRowSet` object). The problem is that the content of this tag is very long (let's say several hundred kilobytes - the data are encoded in Base64), but `input.getText()` reads only 16.394 characters out of it. 
I'm 100 % sure data coming to `XMLStreamReader` are OK.
I found some other answer here, but it doesn't solve my problem, I could of course use some other way how to read the data, but I would like to know what is the problem with this one. 
Does somebody know how to get the whole content?
My code:

```
            input = xmlFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData.getBytes("UTF-8")));

        while(input.hasNext()){
            if(input.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT){
                element = input.getName().getLocalPart();

                switch(element.toLowerCase()){
                    case "transactionresponse":
                        int transactionStatus = 0;

                        transactionResponse = new TransactionResponse(); 
                        for(int i=0; i<input.getAttributeCount(); i++){
                            switch(input.getAttributeLocalName(i)){
                                case "status": transactionStatus = TransactionResponse.getStatusFromName(input.getAttributeValue(i));
                            }
                        }

                        transactionResponse.setStatus(transactionStatus);

                        break;
                    case "dbresponse":
                        for(int i=0; i<input.getAttributeCount(); i++){
                            switch(input.getAttributeLocalName(i)){
                                case "request_id": id = Integer.parseInt(input.getAttributeValue(i)); break;
                                case "status": status = Response.getStatusFromName(input.getAttributeValue(i));
                            }
                        }

                        break;
                }
            }else if(input.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS){
                switch(element.toLowerCase()){
                    case "dbresponse": 
                        String data = input.getText();

                        if(!data.equals("\n")){
                            data = new String(Base64.decode(data), "UTF-8");
                        }

                        Response response = new Response(data, status, id);

                        if(transactionResponse != null){
                            transactionResponse.addResponse(response);
                        }else{
                            this.addResponse(response);
                        }

                        id = -1;
                        status = -1;

                        break;
                }

                element = "";
            }else if(input.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT){
                switch(input.getLocalName().toLowerCase()){
                    case "transactionresponse": this.addTransactionResponse(transactionResponse); transactionResponse = null; break;
                }
            }

            input.next();
```

Comment: Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/limits/index.html. Also check that you fully read the input data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event-driven XML parsers such as `XMLStreamReader` are designed to allow you to parse the XML without having to read it into memory all at one go, which is pretty essential in case you have a very large XML.

The design is such that it reads a certain buffer of data, and gives you events as it runs into "interesting" stuff, such as the beginning of a tag, the end of a tag, and so on.

But the buffer it reads is not infinite, as it is meant to handle large XML files, exactly like the one you have. For this reason, a large text in a tag may be represented by **several consecutive `CHARACTERS` events**.

That is, when you get a `CHARACTERS` event, there is no guarantee that it contains the whole text. If the text is too long for the reader's buffer, you will simply get more `CHARACTERS` events that follow.

Since you are only reading the data from the first `CHARACTERS` event, it is not the whole data.

The proper way to work with such a file is:

- When you get a `START_ELEMENT` event for the element you are interested in, you make preparations for storing the text. For example, create a `StringBuilder`, or open a file for writing, etc.
- For each `CHARACTERS` event that follows, you append the text to your storage (the `StringBuilder`, the file).
- Once you get the `END_ELEMENT` event for the same element, you finish accumulating your data, and do whatever you need to do with it.

In fact, this is what the [`getElementText()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#getElementText%28%29) does for you - accumulates the data in a `StringBuffer` while going through `CHARACTERS` events until it hits the `END_ELEMENT`.

Bottom line: you only know you got the whole data when you hit the `END_ELEMENT` event. There is no guarantee that the text will be in a single `CHARACTERS` event.

Comment: Hi, I am also using the `XmlStreamReader` for my large file but its failing for some reason. If possible can you please have a look at this question and provide your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67667516/jaxb-moxy-unmarshalling-for-large-file-fails-for-some-events

Answer (score 0):

I think the XMLStreamReader chunks the data, so maybe try looping getText() to concatenate all chunks ?

What about getElementText() method ?